# How to use usermod login command?

Tags: rhel

When I try to use:

```
[root@jack-dpp jack]# usermod --login jack-dpp jack
```

I get:

```
usermod: user jack is currently used by process 7622
```

In RHEL 6.6 how to kill all the process and run this command?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ps 7622
```

or

```
top
```

to know what 7622 means, and which other proccess are owned by your user ; then if there is only this one,

```
kill 7622
```

But remember that if your user is logged anywhere (tty or X11 session), you can't modify its login name while he is logged.

Comment: I rejected your edit to the OP's post. Any explanation for why you where you lowercasing `I`?

Comment: I am very sorry, I'm french and I just wanted to improve readability...

Comment: That's is fine in principle, and you are welcome to do so, but keep in mind the differences e.g. in punctuation between English and French, as well as particular style of formatting people use on this site. If you keep an eye on whether your edits are accepted as is, or get improved/rejected (and why), you soon get the hang of how the edit reviewers like them to be.